# Slow Small Webpack 2 Build - Tree Shaking - Sass - Chunking

Tags: sass, webpack-2

I've put together a very basic webpack 2 build, but it seems to be slow for the project size.  The three things I wanted have were:

1. Chunking (js & scss)
2. SCSS compiling
3. Tree Shaking

Webpack seemed to be a good choice for being able to do these things.  I've been using Gulp and Rollup, but the SCSS/Chunking along side of the tree shaking is a nice thing.

It takes around 4000 - 5000ms to compile the build, which wouldn't be the end of the world except the project is so small, so I'm worried about that becoming much larger as a project grows.

I've tried a couple things to improve the speed.

```
resolve : {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname,'src')
}
```

This did help, reducing the time by a couple hundred ms, so that was great.  I tried to take this further by also resolving alias, but that didn't really show any gains as far as I could tell.

I set devTool to eval as well.  Beyond this I haven't really been able to improve things, but I'm sure it's something in the way I've set things up.  It's worth noting that while 'webpack' compiles the build, running the webpack-dev-server doesn't.  It's starts up, hangs on the compile and then crashes.  This may or may not be a separate issue, but I thought it was worth including.

I'm also using ES6 System.import for chunking (just as a note).

I put the project up on git, so feel free to pull it down: https://github.com/loriensleafs/trying-out-webpack2

The webpack.config.js is:

```
var path              = require('path'),
    webpack           = require('webpack'),
    CleanPlugin       = require('clean-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    production        = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

var plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'bundle.css', allChunks: true}),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name      : 'vendor',
        children  : true,
        minChunks : 2
    })
];

if (production) {
    plugins = plugins.concat([
        new CleanPlugin('builds'),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin({
            minChunkSize: 51200, // ~50kb
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle:   true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
            },
        }),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __SERVER__      : !production,
            __DEVELOPMENT__ : !production,
            __DEVTOOLS__    : !production,
            'process.env':   {
                BABEL_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            }
        })
    ]);
}
module.exports = {
    // debug   : !production,
    devTool : production ? false : 'eval',
    entry   : './src',
    output  : {
        path          : 'builds',
        filename      : 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename : 'chunk.js',
        publicPath    : 'builds/'
    },
    resolve : {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname,'src')
    },
    plugins : plugins,
    module  : {
        loaders: [
            {
                test   :   /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                loader : 'url',
                query  : {
                    limit: 10000
                }
            },
            {
                test    : /\.js$/,
                include : /src/,
                exclude : /node_modules/,
                loader  : 'babel'
            },
            {
                test    : /\.scss$/,
                include : /src/,
                exclude : /node_modules/,
                loader  : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css','sass'])
            },
            {
                test   :  /\.html$/,
                loader : 'html'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Thanks for any advice/help folks have on this.  If there's any other helpful info I can post on here please let me know.